# Calculate rolling summary statistics in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table, let's say it contains results on a test taken by students. Every test has been done by one single student, and they can take the test as often as they want. The source table might look like this:

```
  TestID   StudentID   Pass   Score  
 -------- ----------- ------ ------- 
  1        1           0      4      
  2        1           0      6      
  3        2           1      8      
  4        1           1      9      
  5        1           0      2
```

For each time the test was taken, I want to calculate summary statistics on all **previous** results by that student. This is what (the tail of) the result table would look like:

```
  TestID   StudentID   Times Taken   AvPass   AvScore  
 -------- ----------- ------------- -------- --------- 
  4        1           2             0        5        
  5        1           3             .33      6.33
```

I have no idea how to put this in SQL terms, let alone efficiently code it. Would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: What version of SQL Server? 2012 supports `AVG(Score) OVER (PARTITION BY StudentID ORDER BY TestId ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING`

Comment: This sounds promising. What does `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING` do, exactly? My source table isn't necessarily date-ordered, does that matter?

Comment: You only need _some_ column by which to order and it should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that Tim Biegeleisen's answer is not exactly what the question was referring to as it lacks the '**rolling** summary' part. I got the results you look for with the following:

```
SELECT TestId, StudentId, COUNT(*) as TimesTaken
  , ISNULL(AVG(CAST(Pass as decimal)) OVER (PARTITION BY StudentID ORDER BY TestId ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING), 0) as AvPass
  , ISNULL(AVG(CAST(Score as decimal)) OVER (PARTITION BY StudentID ORDER BY TestId ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING), 0) as AvScore
FROM dbo.RollingSummary
GROUP BY TestId, StudentId, Pass, Score
ORDER BY TestId, StudentId
```

The result:

```
TestId  StudentId   TimesTaken  AvPass  AvScore
1   1   1   0.000000    0.000000
2   1   1   0.000000    4.000000
3   2   1   0.000000    0.000000
4   1   1   0.000000    5.000000
5   1   1   0.333333    6.333333
```

**EDIT:** This is also highly efficient as window functions are very performant.